# how can i use javafx 2.0 palette in netbeans?

Tags: java, javafx-2

i install javafx2.0 plugin on netbeans 7.0 but i can't see the palette. 
if netbeans 7 has palette for javafx 2.0 similar to javafx 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have any pallets just project type support and code completion and the samples.

From my usage of it so far

Comment: what time is it add to netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

The visual tool is *JavaFX Composer*. NetBeans IDE 7.0 does not have it yet.

So says a note in this *NetBeans* [*link*](http://netbeans.org/features/javafx/composer.html)

**Quote:**

**The visual layout tool for JavaFX applications.
Note: JavaFX support is currently not available in NetBeans IDE 7.0.**

Answer (score 1):

Support for a JavaFX palette in NetBeans is scheduled for addition NetBeans 7.2, according to the [referring issue tracker](https://www.netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199282) - "code snippets in Palette for common FX idioms like
binding, master-detail data form, etc.".

Furthermore, the [NetBeans 7.2 JavaFX2 plan](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NB72_FX2_Plan) is also scheduled to include interconnection with the JavaFX SceneBuilder - "a standalone visual GUI designer for FXML files".

NetBeans 7.2 is under currently under development.  A [Beta](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_72) is due on the 19th of April 2012 and final release is TBD, but the [NetBeans roadmap](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html) would place it around mid-year.